# save bindings to XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, serialization

According to Microsoft,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx#Extension_References_are_Dereferenced

bindings are not serialized to XAML when using XamlWriter.

Has anyone implemented a way to save these bindings to XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can save bindings to XAML and other expressions using a `BindingConvertor` provided in these posts -

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/xamlwriterandbinding.aspx
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a1984451-4840-4e0f-abc5-8a8e34a4f8ca

I have used it myself and it works great.